# Huawei App Signing can not create zip file

Tags: android, keystore, huawei-developers, android-app-signing, appgallery-connect

In Huawei App Gallery I have to update an existing aab application. Site redirects me to App signing page and there are steps that I have to follow in order to sign the app successfully. These are the steps provided:

1. Obtain the pepk.jar file from the Internet or another legitimate source.
2. Export and encrypt your private key and public key certificate into a ZIP file. Parameters in bold must be replaced as needed. Then, enter your data storage location and key password as prompted.
   java -jar pepk.jar --keystore test.jks --alias test --output=output.zip --encryptionkey=<some_encryption_key> --include-cert
3. Upload the ZIP file containing the private key and public key certificate. (The ZIP file contains only certificate.pem and encryptedPrivateKey.)

Now I have 2 problems.

**First** one is, when I run the code in 2nd step in CMD. I get **include-cert flag is not provided error**. However when I write **--include-cert=certificate.pem** or **--include-cert certificate.pem** it **says flag is unrecognized**.

**Second** one is, I put certificate.pem and private key to folder and then turn it into ZIP. But when I click on submit it gives me **Make sure the package contains only the certificate.pem and encryptedPrivateKey files** error. Is not encryptedPrivateKey is the file that is exported by AndroidStudio when you generate an app bundle or Apk into the same location with .pepk extension?

I don't know what am I missing in order to sign my application. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "No value provided for flag: include-cert" is displayed, the pepk.jar file is incorrect. You need to replace it with a correct one.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-faq-0000001052944432

Answer (score 1):

> I get include-cert flag is not provided error. However when I write --include-cert=certificate.pem or --include-cert certificate.pem it says flag is unrecognized.

It is recommended that you **do not** change the command and follow the commands in the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-newapp-0000001052418290).

You could click [here](https://infocenter-en.dra.agchosting.link/interactive/iteach.html?language=en_us#c943f69e_8ee6_fb19_3861_27937201a702) to try out.

And this is the [App Signing Operation Guide video](https://mos-vod-drcn.dbankcdn.cn/P_VT/video_injection/7F13463AB/v3/942838481192717267746424576/MP4Mix_H.264_1920x1080_6000_HEAAC1_PVC_NoCut.mp4) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the problem still occurs. I have required files ready but when I try to create the ZIP file in CMD it still gives me Error saying "No value provided for flag include-cert". I could not find solution or other questions related to include-cert flag.

Comment: Finally managed to find the problem. Turns out the pepk.jar file is incorrect so it is needed to be changed with a correct one.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-faq-0000001052944432